# 数字文字の出現回数を *を縦に並べたグラフで表したい。

Tags: c

以下のプログラム（`*` を横に並べるグラフ）を元に、数字文字の出現回数を `*` を縦に並べたグラフで表したいのですが、どうすればいいのかがわかりません。

とりあえず、`*` を横に並べるグラフは以下のようにプログラムを作成しました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,ch;
    int cnt[10]={0};
    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
        if('0'<=ch && ch<='9'){
            cnt[ch-'0']++;
        }
    }
    printf("数字文字の出現回数\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        putchar('\'');
        putchar('0'+i);
        putchar('\'');
        printf(":");
        for(j=0;j<cnt[i];j++)
         putchar('*');
         putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

上記プログラムの実行結果

```
$ ./a.out
223467.3345
(CTRL+D)
数字文字の出現回数
'0':
'1':
'2':**
'3':***
'4':**
'5':*
'6':*
'7':*
'8':
'9':
```

今回作成したいプログラムでの期待している実行結果

```
$ ./a.out
223467.3345
(CTRL+D)
数字文字の出現回数

         *
      *  *  *
      *  *  *  *  *  *
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

毎度、初歩的な質問申し訳ありませんが、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

学校の課題等でCでやることが決められているとかでなければ、描画ツール(たとえばgnuplotなど)で描くようにするのがやりやすいと思います。

一例ですが作ってみました。

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i,j,ch,max;
    int cnt[10]={0};
    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
        if('0'<=ch && ch<='9'){
            cnt[ch-'0']++;
        }
    }

    /* あらかじめ最も多く出現した値を調べておく */
    max = 0;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
        if ( max < cnt[ i ] ) {
            max = cnt[ i ];
        }
    }

    printf("数字文字の出現回数\n\n");
    /* グラフの上のほうから順番に表示する */
    for ( j = max; j >= 1 ; --j ) {
        for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ) {
            if ( cnt[ i ] >= j ) {
                printf( "*  " );
            }
            else {
                printf( "   " );
            }
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    /* 横軸の数字を表示する */
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i ) {
        printf( "%1d  ", i );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

実行結果

```
$ ./a.out
0.#12345678911122233333
数字文字の出現回数

         *                    
         *                    
   *  *  *                    
   *  *  *                    
   *  *  *                    
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  
$ ./a.out
0111111111123
数字文字の出現回数

   *                          
   *                          
   *                          
   *                          
   *                          
   *                          
   *                          
   *                          
   *                          
*  *  *  *                    
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。プログラムソースにコメントを記載してくれたので、とてもわかり易く、理解が深まりました。